# Jquery selecting text between parentheses in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an array based on selected values from multiple select boxes:

> Term 03 (-1000),1 (+1000),Price (+3000),1 (+1500),--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--

Comma-separated. As you can see, some values have text in parentheses. I need to take these values in parentheses and sum them, therefore the `+` and `-` characters should remain.

Values (+1000), (+3000), (-1000) represent changes of price: + indicates the product will be more expensive, - represents the product will be cheaper. The result of this should be a number that indicates change of the price - e.g. 1500 - the product will cost more than basic price, or e.g. -3000 - the product will be cheaper.
Thanks in advance.
Tom

Comment: We didn't get you ..

Comment: "brackets" , or parenthesis ? If possible can post actual array literal ? Is requirements to sum `-1 + +1` , etc. ?

Comment: is `1 000` the same numerically as `1000`?

Comment: define what `sum` means in this context. Provide real array sample and expected output

Comment: It'd probably be easier to do this with the values *before* you glue them together in a string.

Comment: oh, sorry for misunderstanding. Values (+1 000), (+3 000), (-1 000) represent changes of price: + indicates the product will be more expensive, - represents the product will be cheaper. I can delete spaces in the array, so let's presume values I am interested in are in the scheme (+1000), (-1000) format. The result of this should be a number that indicates change of the price. Hope I made myself clear now :)

Comment: Only very few numbers in JS have a leading `+`. You can omit it, and a number will still be positive.

Comment: @tom, no it is not clear and you should update the question with sample array code (your text is not a js array) and expected output as well as clarifications

Comment: Is requirement to sum `(+1000) + (+3000) + (-1000) = 3000` ?

Comment: the requirement is to sum any and all values in parentheses. Number of values in parentheses may vary - depending on what user chooses in select boxes that create the array. Values "--" in the array specify that user did not select anything in that particular select box. So I need to a) identify all values in parentheses b) sum them together. The final value can be positive or negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not great with regular expressions I've made a version that does not "use" them, this way it's more readable and easier to see what's going on and how it goes about doing it. Not to say you should not use regular expressions.

For this algorithm we are basically looking through each item, checking if they have valid parentheses, then if we have `+` we add the value inside the parentheses, otherwise if we have `-` we subtract (assuming those are the only two you can have):

```
for(items in array) {
    var firstPar = array[items].indexOf("(");
    var secondPar = array[items].indexOf(")");
    // Check of the item has parentheses and are like this (...)
    if( (firstPar > 0 && secondPar > 0) && (secondPar > firstPar) ) {
        // Get the number from the string
        var value = array[items].substring(firstPar+2, secondPar);
        value = parseInt(value); // To Number
        if( array[items].charAt(firstPar+1) == '+')
            ProductPrice += value; // If "+" add
        else  
            ProductPrice -= value;// If "-" subtract
    }
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kcc35v9z/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have comma-separated values, with numbers in them to extract. Start by splitting the input to an array, then for each item, extract the value using regexp for example:

```
/\(([+-])(\d+)\)/ //will search for a sign (+/-) and a number between parenthesis
```

applied to an item will result in an array having the sign in second position and the number in 3rd position

```
/\(([+-])(\d+)\)/.exec('Term 03 (-1000)') //--> ['Term 03 (-1000)', '-', '1000']
```

Use reduce to sum the all with consideration to the sign:

```
var changes = str.split(',').reduce(function(sum, item){
  var matches = /\(([+-])(\d+)\)/.exec(item);
  if(matches) {
   return sum + (matches[1] === '-' ? -1 : 1) * parseInt(matches[2]);
  } else {
    return sum;
  }
}, 0));
```

**P.S.:** If you have already an array, you can remove the `.split(',')` part.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var sum = 0; 
csv.replace(/\([^)]+\)/gi, function (str) { sum += parseInt(str,10); return str; }
```

Didn't test code. Anyway idea is to use regex to loop all parenthesis and then inside replace function, convert matched string to integer and add it to sum.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work with the rather cumbersome code below. It does work with both positive and negative integers.

```
var result = arr.map(function (el) {
  if (el.indexOf('(') > -1 && el.indexOf(')') > -1) {
    return Number(el.match(/\(([\+\- 0-9]*)\)/g)[0].replace(/[\(\) ]/g , ''));
  }
}).filter(function (el) {
  if (typeof el !== undefined) {
    return el;
  }
}).reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p + c;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e8mmu5xy/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var arr = "Term 03 (-1000),1 (+1000),Price (+3000),1 (+1500),--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--".split(",")
, sum = 0;
arr.map(function(v, k) {
  // cast `v` value as `Number` , e.g., `[-1000, 1000, 3000, 1500]`
  var n = Number(v.replace(/\w+[^\(+\d+\)]|[\(|\)]/g, "")) || null;
  // add `n` Number's at `sum` , e.g., `-1000 + 1000 + 3000 + 1500` = `4500`
  sum += n
});
// console.log(sum); // `4500`
```

```js
var arr = "Term 03 (-1000),1 (+1000),Price (+3000),1 (+1500),--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--".split(",")
, sum = 0;
arr.map(function(v, k) {
  // cast `v` value as `Number` , e.g., `[-1000, 1000, 3000, 1500]`
  var n = Number(v.replace(/\w+[^\(+\d+\)]|[\(|\)]/g, "")) || null;
  // add `n` Number's at `sum` , e.g., `-1000 + 1000 + 3000 + 1500` = `4500`
  sum += n
});
    
    document.write(sum) // `4500`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```